# jQuery show div on radio select with auto check radio option

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm using jQuery to show/hide div on radio select. This works fine, but i wan't to extend it, so specific radio is selected by default on page load.

Here's HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="Payment1">Payment1
<input type="radio" id="Payment2">Payment2

<div id="PaymentContainer1" style="display:none;">Payment 1 container</div>
<div id="PaymentContainer2" style="display:none;">Payment 2 container</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).change(function () {
    if ($('#Payment1').prop('checked')) {
        $('#PaymentContainer1').show();
    } else {
        $('#PaymentContainer1').hide();
    }

    if ($('#Payment2').prop('checked')) {
        $('#PaymentContainer2').show();
    } else {
        $('#PaymentContainer2').hide();
    }
});
```

Here's fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/teva/yauCs/1/

I tried adding

```
$("#Payment1").prop("checked", true);
```

but it doesn't work.

thanks

Edit
Any way to make fields in specific div to not just hide,  but disabled? I'm using one form for all divs and when i hide them with jQuery, form doesn't post, because fields are empty. So, hide div and disable inputs. Is this possible with jQuery?
Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, Why are you using .change event on document, it may give errors when you do some other change in the page.

better use like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){


    if ($('#Payment1').is(':checked')) {
        $('#PaymentContainer1').show();
    } else {
        $('#PaymentContainer1').hide();
    }

    if ($('#Payment2').is(':checked')) {
        $('#PaymentContainer2').show();
    } else {
        $('#PaymentContainer2').hide();
    }
        });
});
$("#Payment1").prop("checked", true).change();
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yauCs/10/)

You have some other issue, in your case both radio getting selected, ideally this is not the way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){

    if ($('#Payment1').is(':checked')) {

        $('.containner').hide();
        $('#PaymentContainer1').show();
    } else {
        $('#PaymentContainer1').hide();
    }

    if ($('#Payment2').is(':checked')) {

        $('.containner').hide();
        $('#PaymentContainer2').show();
    } else {
        $('#PaymentContainer2').hide();
    }
        });
});
$("#Payment1").prop("checked", true).change();
```

[Perfect Radio Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yauCs/13/)

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
  $("input[type=radio]").change(function () {

   if ($('#Payment1').prop('checked')) {
      $('#PaymentContainer1').show();
  } else {
      $('#PaymentContainer1').hide();
   }

   if ($('#Payment2').prop('checked')) {
      $('#PaymentContainer2').show();
   } else {
      $('#PaymentContainer2').hide();
  }
});

$("#Payment2").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
```

here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/yauCs/5/

Answer (score 0):

Add `name="payment"` in both `radio` so they will act as group and call `click` after `change` handler

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="payment" id="Payment1">Payment1
<input type="radio" name="payment" id="Payment2">Payment2
<div id="PaymentContainer1" style="display:none;">Payment 1 container</div>
<div id="PaymentContainer2" style="display:none;">Payment 2 container</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).change(function () {
    if ($('#Payment1').prop('checked')) {
        $('#PaymentContainer1').show();
    } else {
        $('#PaymentContainer1').hide();
    }

    if ($('#Payment2').prop('checked')) {
        $('#PaymentContainer2').show();
    } else {
        $('#PaymentContainer2').hide();
    }
});
$("#Payment1").click();
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/yauCs/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `$(document).change()` as you will be listening to events for every element in the DOM, [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) allows the elements to be dynamically added and still work.

```
$(document).on('change','input',function () {

    if ($('#Payment1').prop('checked')) {
        $('#PaymentContainer1').show();
    } else {
        $('#PaymentContainer1').hide();
    }

    if ($('#Payment2').prop('checked')) {
        $('#PaymentContainer2').show();
    } else {
        $('#PaymentContainer2').hide();
    }
});

$("#Payment1").prop("checked", true);
```

Also set your radio's name to the same thing to ensure only one is selected

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yauCs/9/)

Answer (score 0):

very little mistake in this code, try this i hope this will work prefectly
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Payment1").attr("checked", true);

```
if ($('#Payment1').prop('checked')) {
    $('#PaymentContainer1').show();
} else {
    $('#PaymentContainer1').hide();
}

if ($('#Payment2').prop('checked')) {
    $('#PaymentContainer2').show();
} else {
    $('#PaymentContainer2').hide();
}
```

});